# What text do I have to put in mc's File Find text field "Content:"?

Tags: midnight-commander

Midnight Commander 3.4.8.1 > File Find. What text do I have to put in the »Content:« text field and in the other fields? I tried several settings in the other fields but mc always returned no result. (This is not explained in 'man mc'.) My hope is to perform some grep-like action using mc. http://svn.dd-wrt.com:8000/browser//src/router/mc2/src/filemanager/find.c did not enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

I managed now to obtain meaningful results. I probably always had set the mask in the »File Name:« text field too narrow. I set it now to '*', and now it works. I asserted also »Use Shell Pattern«, »Search for Contents« and »Case«.

Comment: If this post is the answer to your question, you should accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer. That way, it'll appear in search results as answered and hopefully help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You must compelte all the fields that are required for a complete search. You must tell `mc` everything, like:

- where to search (start at)
- file name (what file you are looking for; here you can use wildcards like `*`)
- what is inside that file you are intersted in (content)

The output of the search will be like: `no:filename` where:

- **`no`** is the number of the line in the file where your content was found.
- **`filename`** is the name of the file find by search according to your parameters from "Start at" and "File name."